# Layouts are not including in controller definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails3 I have many layouts in my project, I am defining layout'layout_name' at the top of my controller. I am facing problem like all the layouts are rendering but only one layout is not rendering .. Can anybody say what is the reason?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you want to do? E.g. you want to have a standard layout for all views, but only for one controller a special one. And then post the parts of the code you think are reasonable. What does `one layout is not rendering` means? Is that layout not rendered at all (exception), or is it renderer by the default layout?

Comment: Exactly .. I want a single layout for all but not for this one.  layout 'familywebsite' because this is not applying I am using render :layout=>familywebsite in all definitions which is working

Comment: Just edit your question, so it is easier for others to see the whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [tutorial about rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), especially the section 2.2.13 "Finding Layout". There are the different options listed:

- Find the layout for all actions of one controller

  - Name the layout in the directory  `app/views/layouts` as your controller. So when your controller is named `WorkItemsController`, the corresponding layout is named `work_items.htmlerb`
  - You may change that convention in your controller with the following code, that will search for a layout named `work.html.erb`:
    `class WorkItemsController < ApplicationController; layout "work"; ...`
- There are even variations which allow the dynamic dispatch or even a layout by action.

Have a look at the [API for layout](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout) to see all options possible here.